# Add a specific file of a project into the release GitLab

Tags: gitlab, release, cicd

I'm developing embedded firmware using C and IAR as IDE.

On compiling, the IDE generates a .hex file in a specific folder which (let's say it's `/Obj` basically is the full code compiled. It can be flashed directly to the microcontroller.

Now, once I got to generate a Release on GitLab, it creates 4 Assets in the form of

- Source code (zip)
- Source code (tar.gz)
- Source code (tar.bz2)
- Source code (tar)

Now, I would like to add my *.hex* file in it as a single file when I generate the release.

I can use all the CI/CD features inside Gitlab as I would like do it automatically when I generate the release

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: I don't think this is a git question.

Comment: For reference https://forum.gitlab.com/t/add-a-specific-file-of-a-project-into-the-release-gitlab/82124/4